# Onclick replace item information in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The goal is to build an estimator interface for my customer.

So I've several boxes with items the customer can add or remove (domain name, hosting, ...).

The result of the selected items is shown here:

```
<ul class="calculator__sidebar-ul">
</ul>
```

The problem with my code is each time a user click on an item, it adds a new line whereas it should replace the one in place.

How can I change this behavior ?

```js
$('input[name="hosting"]').click(function() {
    value = $(this).data('value');
    title = $(this).data('title');

    if($('li #hosting').length == 1) { $('li #hosting').remove(); }
    $('.calculator__sidebar-ul').append('<li id="hosting">'+ title +'<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + '+ value +' $</span></li>');
});


$('input[name="domain"]').click(function() {
    value = $(this).data('value');
    title = $(this).data('title');

    if($('li #domain').length == 1) { $('li #domain').remove(); }
    $('.calculator__sidebar-ul').append('<li id="domain">'+ title +'<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + '+ value +' $</span></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Hosting (1 year)</h4>
<div class="form__form-group">
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="0" data-title="No hosting" name="hosting">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">No hosting
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 0$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="200" data-title="Yes, add one hosting" name="hosting">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">Yes, add one hosting
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 200$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>




<h4>Domain name (1 year)</h4>
<div class="form__form-group">
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="0" data-title="No domain" name="domain">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">No domain
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 0$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="50" data-title="Yes, add one domain" name="domain">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">Yes, add one domain
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 50$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>



<ul class="calculator__sidebar-ul">
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @freefaller has the solution in the comment above, but the reason for your issue is that `li` *is* `#hosting`, so `length` is always `0`. Once you change to `html()` you can remove the `if` statement completely

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the reason why I think I need `if($('li #hosting').length == 1) {}` is if the user change the choice of the radio.

Comment: You don't need it. `html()` will overwrite any previous content, so the prior selections have no relevance to the current content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend more this approach.

With this one you'll only update the `<ul>` part without duplicating your jquery code.

```
// Update the <ul> part:
<ul class="calculator__sidebar-ul hidden">
    <li id="hosting"></li>
    <li id="domain"></li>
</ul>

// Update the jQuery code
$('input[class="radio-btn__radio"]').click(function() {
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    value = $(this).data('value');
    title = $(this).data('title');

    $('#' + name).empty();
    $('#' + name).html(title + '<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + ' + value + ' $</span>');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following** was written when the question only gave information about a single section...

Using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will add the HTML to the end of the HTML that already exists in the element.

Instead, use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which will replace everything...

```
$('.calculator__sidebar-ul').html('<li id="hosting">'+ title +'<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + '+ value +' $</span></li>');
```

And as @Rory says in his comment, using `.html()` means you no longer need to remove the existing items before hand (which wouldn't have worked anyway), so you can delete the following line...

```
if($('li #hosting').length == 1) { $('li #hosting').remove(); }
```

---

**Updated...**

In light of the extra information provided by the OP that there are **two** sections that need to drive the display...

Your code is not removing the existing `<li>` element because `$("li #hosting")` will only find an element **in** `<li>` which has an `id="hosting"`.

Instead you just want to find and remove `$("#hosting")`.

In this situation, your use of `.append` is correct.

```js
$('input[name="hosting"]').click(function() {
    value = $(this).data('value');
    title = $(this).data('title');

    $('#hosting').remove();
    $('.calculator__sidebar-ul').append('<li id="hosting">'+ title +'<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + '+ value +' $</span></li>');
});


$('input[name="domain"]').click(function() {
    value = $(this).data('value');
    title = $(this).data('title');

    $('#domain').remove();
    $('.calculator__sidebar-ul').append('<li id="domain">'+ title +'<span class="calculator__sidebar-price"> + '+ value +' $</span></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Hosting (1 year)</h4>
<div class="form__form-group">
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="0" data-title="No hosting" name="hosting">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">No hosting
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 0$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="200" data-title="Yes, add one hosting" name="hosting">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">Yes, add one hosting
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 200$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>




<h4>Domain name (1 year)</h4>
<div class="form__form-group">
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="0" data-title="No domain" name="domain">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">No domain
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 0$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-btn calculator__radio-btn">
        <input class="radio-btn__radio" type="radio" data-value="50" data-title="Yes, add one domain" name="domain">
        <span class="radio-btn__radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="radio-btn__label">Yes, add one domain
            <span class="calculator__color_label">+ 50$</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>



<ul class="calculator__sidebar-ul">
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for your help. I've add the JS Fiddle link to better image the problem I have when I have two item (hosting + domain).

Comment: Don't use jsfiddle, update your question to use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) with a [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I will try but I do not know to use it.

Comment: Good thing I provided [a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) on how to use it then

Comment: Hum. I think it's now working. I've also remove the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Your original question said nothing about multiple items, therefore what you asked originally has changed massively compared to what you're asking now